# Check if a SQL table exists in C#

Tags: c#, sql

```
            var conn = new SqlConnection("");

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string s = $"SELECT Email FROM {tableName} WHERE {query}";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                int email = reader.GetOrdinal("Email");                

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var response = new User
                    {                       
                        Email = reader.IsDBNull(email) ? null : reader.GetString(email)
                    };
                    emailList.Add(response);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

How do I update this code to verify if a table with name {tableName} exists in sql database before executing this code.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an way using ADO.NET to determine if a table exists in a database that works with any data provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528361/is-there-an-way-using-ado-net-to-determine-if-a-table-exists-in-a-database-that)

Comment: Query SQL's `sys.tables` with a specific table name.

Comment: There are several ways how to check it table exists in the database: https://database.guide/6-ways-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-sql-server-t-sql-examples/

Comment: @MohammadMirmostafa can you please give an example?

Comment: @user989988 Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following query and substitute `{tablename}` with the name of the table, you are looking for:

`SELECT name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [schema], create_date, object_id, modify_date FROM sys.tables WHERE name = {tablename}`